# Three Js gltf object material

Tags: jquery, three.js, mapping, textures

I am trying to change texture of gltf object with jquery array passed in variables. Following is the code where I am stuck or not able to apply click and change material.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

import { OrbitControls } from './assets/js/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from './assets/js/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { RGBELoader } from './assets/js/jsm/loaders/RGBELoader.js';
import { RoomEnvironment } from './assets/js/jsm/environments/RoomEnvironment.js';

import { GUI } from './assets/js/jsm/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js';

let camera, scene, renderer, controls, textureLoader, obj;
let grid;

//Textures Array
var myObject = ['1-2.jpg', '2-2.jpg', '3-1.jpg', '4-1.jpg', '4-2.jpg', '5-1.jpg', '6-1.jpg', '8-2.jpg', '9-2.jpg', '10-1.jpg'];
        
// Array loop append into list
$.each(myObject, function (keyName, keyValue) {
$('.textures').append('<li data-texture="' + keyValue + '"><img src="assets/images/' + keyValue + '"></li>');
        });

init();
animate();

function init() {

const container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 20);
camera.position.set( 6, 4, 7);

scene = new THREE.Scene();
            
// texture
textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const texture1 = textureLoader.load('assets/images/1-2.jpg');
var texture = new THREE.MeshMatcapMaterial( {map: texture1});

// load obj gltf
new GLTFLoader().setPath('assets/objects/gltf/').load('pocketsquare.gltf', function (gltf) {

obj = gltf.scene;
obj.traverse ( ( o ) => {
if ( o.isMesh ) {
o.material.map = texture1;
}
});
                
scene.add( obj );

});

// click on image to get value
$('.textures li').on('click', function () {
var text = 'assets/images/'+$(this).data('texture');
texture1 = textureLoader.load(text);
console.log(texture);
obj.traverse ( ( o ) => {
if ( o.isMesh ) {
o.material.map = texture1;
}
});
                
scene.update;
});

// renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const environment = new RoomEnvironment();
const pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(renderer);

scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
scene.environment = pmremGenerator.fromScene(environment).texture;

// controls
controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.minDistance = 1;
controls.maxDistance = 10;
controls.target.set(0, 0.35, 0);
controls.update();

// grid enviornemnt
grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 80, 80, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
grid.material.opacity = 0.05;
grid.material.depthWrite = false;
grid.material.transparent = true;
scene.add( grid );

//obj.material.needsUpdate = true

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

}

function onWindowResize() {
camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
//obj.rotation.x += 0.005;
//obj.rotation.y += 0.001;
controls.update(); // required if damping enabled

render();

}

function render() {
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

This is the complete code which brings canvas environment and i've placed a ul with class textures.

i've change code inside the click function

```
// click on image to get value
$('.textures li').on('click', function () {
var text = './assets/images/'+$(this).data('texture');                
texture = textureLoader.load(text);
obj.children[1].material.map = texture;
obj.matrixAutoUpdate  = false;
obj.updateMatrix();
});
```

problem solved